# Use a varchar in MySQL IN() Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which holds different states, I am trying to filter on these states using the id which is a smallint.

To do this I am using the IN() statement:

```
Declare StateList varchar(150);
Declare States varchar(150);
set @StateList = State;
set @States = '';

if (@StateList Like '%1%')then 
    if(LENGTH(@States) > 0) then set @States := Concat(@States, ',1,2');
    else set @States := Concat(@States, '1,2');
    end if;
end if;
if(@StateList Like '%2%')then 
    if(LENGTH(@States) > 0) then set @States := Concat(@States, ',3');
    else set @States := Concat(@States, '3');
    end if;
end if;
if(@StateList Like '%3%')then   
    if(LENGTH(@States) > 0) then set @States := Concat(@States, ',4,5');
    else set @States := Concat(@States, '4,5');
    end if;
end if;
Select * 
from ticket_state
Where ticket_state in (@States)
```

Now when the input is say `12` the value of `@States` should be `1,2,3` which I was hoping would go straight into the in statement as `in(1,2,3)` but this is only returning the first number in the sequence for states, which is what I don't want.

Any one know why this isn't working?

Comment: It seems to me that @States is a list of varchar values. That is, each one must be enclosed in apostrophes.

Comment: Just a side comment: you are mixing user variable declarations (set @variable_name=...) with compound statement variable declaration (declare variable_name). You do not need the 2 declare statements at the beginning, you are not using those variables in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statement like `IN(1,2,3)` would do do job, but that's not what you have here. You have a single string, so it's like `IN('1,2,3')`

You can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to achieve what you want.

example:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(2, '1,2,3'); -- returns 2
```

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ticket_state
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(ticket_state,@States)
```